# I don't see Add in-app advertising when i uploaded my App in windowsphone store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ads

I have a Developer account in windowsphone store, this is my first time uploading an app.

I've added the AdControl correctly in my App and it works right when testing in my device.

here a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206730%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in msdn.microsoft showing steps to publish the app with your pubCenter pubCenter Application ID and the Ad units.

in the third step :

> In the **App Submission Hub**, under **More Choices**, click **Add in-app advertising** to start creating ad units.

But actually i don't see nothing about More choices or in-app advertising in my account.

I found in the internet someone have published a screen shut

[image: i don't have that line in my account]

i don't have that line in my account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not live in one of the supported countries listed [here](http://help.bingads.microsoft.com/help.aspx?project=adcenter_pub_rtw_ss&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=pub_conc_payment_policy.htm):

Australia,
Austria,
Belgium,
Brazil,
Canada,
Chile,
Colombia,
Czech Republic,
Denmark,
Finland,
France,
Germany,
Greece,
Hong Kong,
Hungary,
India,
Ireland,
Israel,
Italy,
Japan,
Luxemburg,
Mexico,
Netherlands,
New Zealand,
Norway,
Poland,
Portugal,
Singapore,
South Africa,
South Korea,
Spain,
Sweden,
Switzerland,
Taiwan,
United Kingdom

Comment: you're right i live in Tunisia. But why we don't have the right to live reste of the world ? we are all humains why is this discrimination! no pubcenter no admob .. :(

Comment: I think only Microsoft can answer this